# How can I append data in a excel file using python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I had been working on tkinter programming and I am stuck at this point. What I  want to accomplish is whatever data I enter in my entry box and hit a button , that data should get added to the excel file at a particular location. When I enter second data in the same entry box it should fill the data in the second column or row after I hit the button. The first data should also be in the excel when appending the second value. Right now , if I enter the second data the first data gets deleted.

```
def btnClick():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("python sheet1")
    sheet1.write(0,counter,Ent1.get())
    workbook.save("PythonTest")
    print("Created")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use below code to demostrate what is wrong here so  what happen is for every btnclick it re-create  PythonTest.xlsx and overrite  if you try below code the final out put a have number 4 in the excel because I call `btnClick()` method 4 times

```
import xlwt

counter = 0


def btnClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1

    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("python sheet1")
    sheet1.write(0, counter, counter) # added counter to write
    workbook.save("PythonTest.xlsx")
    print("Created")


btnClick()
btnClick()
btnClick()
btnClick()
```

[image: OutPut1]

If I change the code as below

```
import xlwt

counter = 0

workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("python sheet1")

def btnClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    sheet1.write(0, counter, counter)
    print("Created")


btnClick()
btnClick()
btnClick()
btnClick()

workbook.save("PythonTest.xlsx")
```

[image: outputTwo]

out put excel will have 1, 2 ,3 ,4. What I m try to tell you is that you should `close()` (`workbook.save("PythonTest.xlsx")`) the workBook after you enter every data . Or if not you should use some other library that can read existing or created excel like : openpyxl to read and adde for every button click.

you should create and close workbook out side the btn click method

Comment: Thanks , that worked , thank you for helping me out.Cheers